# Is there a possibility in pySpark to search a string within two separate words?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm looking to find a way in python spark to search a string with separate two words. for example: IPhone x  or Samsun s10 ...

I want to give a text file and (Iphone x) as a composite string for example, and get result then.

All what i find in the internet is just one word count

Comment: Are you asking whether it is possible to tell whether a string consisting of two words is present in each value in a column?

Comment: i'm looking to search the count of  "IPhone X" in a text file using pyspark

Answer (score 0):

IUUC:

In spark 2.0 and if you were gunna read it from a file, for exemple a .csv file:

```
df = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").load("pathtoyourcsvfile.csv")
```

then you can filter it using regex like this:

```
pattern = "\s+(word1|word2)\s+"
filtered = df.filter(df['<thedesiredcolumnhere>'].rlike(pattern))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to write your own UDF combine with [wordsegmente](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/wordsegment/) to segment your words, and you can add new word to the dictionary to help library to segment new words, such as **"Iphone x"**

For example:

```
>>> from wordsegment import clean
>>> clean('She said, "Python rocks!"')
'shesaidpythonrocks'
>>> segment('She said, "Python rocks!"')
['she', 'said', 'python', 'rocks']
```

If you don't want to use library, you can also see [Word segmentation using dynamic programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22194219/word-segmentation-using-dynamic-programming)

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer:

```
# give a file
rdd = sc.textFile("/root/PycharmProjects/Spark/file") 

# give a composite string
string_ = "Iphone x" 

# filer by line containing the string
new_rdd = rdd.filter(lambda line: string_ in line) 

# collect these lines
rt = str(new_rdd.collect()) 

# apply regex to find all words and count 
count = re.findall(string_, rt) them
```